# Как определить количество кластеров в матрице?

Tags: алгоритм, анализ-данных

Необходим алгоритм для определения количества кластеров в матрице 10х10. Матрица заполнена целыми значениями от 0 до 255.

Для примера, в прикрепленной картинкой матрице, количество таких кластеров должно быть равно 3.

[image: Пример матрицы для которой необходимо определить количество областей]

Comment: Что такое кластер? Каков принцип его определения? Ваши попытки решить вашу задачу?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936518/how-do-i-automate-the-number-of-clusters

Comment: Почему у вас последняя срока выделена в отдельный кластер? Кстати, на вашей картинке как минимум пять кластеров, хотя почему-то вы говорите о трех.